# How are you meant to use Prompt, Description, Ordering when applying data-annotations in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor, data-annotations

I have a view model with a property on it that looks like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Some Property", Description = "This is description", Prompt = "This is prompt")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = RequiredFieldMessage)]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

But this does not seem to render anything extra in the view. Do you need to do some additional work?

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SomeProperty )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SomeProperty , 5, 80, null)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeProperty )
    </div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not all of the built in EditorTemplates take advantage of all of the DataAnnotations, but they are there for when you write your own EditorTemplates you can leverage them.

Ordering doesn't really apply unless you are doing `DisplayForModel` or `EditorForModel` where its showing multiple editors for all the properties on the model, it can then order the Editor's appropriately.

If you wanted to take advantage of the `Description` and `Prompt` metadata you could write your own `String` EditorTemplate:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { 
    @title = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Description, 
    @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark})
```

Comment: I think it should be ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark. I had hoped that it would have been a little more dynamic than that. I do not want to have to use EditorTemplates for all my inputs. "placeholder" isn't even supported in IE. :( - Thanks anyway, this seems like the best answer.

Comment: Fixed the code sample.  Yeah its annoying, but once you develop a good set of reusable generic EditorTemplates you can just reuse them over and over.  Some people have attempted this as I have seen some stuff on Nuget, but not sure if there is a definitive project.

Comment: Maybe its time to start a new GitHub project :)

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/srkirkland/Html5MvcTemplates, but it doesn't contain the watermark functionality, going to try to add it and see if I can get a pull.

Comment: Excellent stuff, i never really considered using templates seriously. Watermarking might be difficult due to the ie incompatibility with the html 5 placeholder tag, i think everyone does it with JS.

Comment: Yeah, in IE you could script something, but the template could still just spit out the attribute and the code on the client side could do it.  I've seen some modernizr + jquery combos to do that kind of thing in any browser not supporting it: http://uniquemethod.com/html5-placeholder-text-with-modernizr-and-jquery-fallback

Comment: Name is for Label.
Description is for Title.
Prompt is for Placeholder.