# How to use data-annotations [Display( Prompt="Password")] in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, placeholder

I have seen many examples on SO<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037905/how-are-you-meant-to-use-prompt-description-ordering-when-applying-data-annota)</sup><sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension)</sup> for how to use `[Display( Prompt="Password")]` in mvc 3.

I wonder if there is any direct implementation in MVC 5. I am using as below

**Model**

```
[Display(Name="Password", Prompt="Password")]
public string Current { get; set; }
```

**view**

```
 @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password.Current, 
                          new { @class = "form-control". placeholder = ?  })
```

Comment: what result do you get?

Comment: What's the problem? Where's the question?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960673/displayprompt-mvc3